# error: Wrong architecture 'amd64' installing Openstudio

Tags: software-installation

I have installed ubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386 alongside the Windows Vista home edition 32 bit on my laptop, and now when I want to [install Openstudio](https://openstudio.nrel.gov/downloads) on Ubuntu I get this error:

```
Wrong architecture 'amd64'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which Openstudio file have you downloaded?

Comment: Hey Mitch, I downloaded this file: OpenStudio-1.2.0.31bd0f02a9-Linux.deb
from this page: https://openstudio.nrel.gov/downloads

Comment: you downloaded a 64 bit openstudio which was not supported by your architecture.

Comment: but that is the only file which i could find on the website!
can you help me to find a proper 32 bit openstudio file to install Avinash?! Thanks a lot....

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the 64-bits version of Ubuntu for OpenStudio to work.

If you are sure that your system can handle a 64-bit operating system, download a 64-bit image of Ubuntu, install it, then try again installing OpenStudio.

If your system cannot run a 64-bit operating system, then you won't be able to get OpenStudio to work on Linux.

Comment: This does, of course, assume their system can run 64-bit Ubuntu.  If their processor is sufficiently old they can't put 64bit on it.

Comment: @ThomasW. pretty much, since I need registration to download the file, I couldn't test myself, but yes, if his system doesn't support 64-bits he is more or less doomed.

Comment: Indeed.  I did revise your answer a little, you can revert if you want, but I think this is a little bit better (with the slightly more verbose answer here)